# ngx-translate output return without translate

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I used this tutorial

https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/ng2-translate/

everything run , I can take json format  but not print output

en.json

```
{
    "HELLO": "hola",
    "hi":"sa"
  }
```

.ts constructor;

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }
```

.html block;

```
<div style="width: 100%;">           
        <p class="baslik">ACCOUNT</p>
      <button ion-item>
          <ion-label>{{ 'hi' | translate }}</ion-label>
      </button>
      <button ion-item>
          <ion-label>{{ 'hi' | translate }}</ion-label>
      </button>
  </div>
```

but output;

hi

hi

when add button click event , this code block;

```
this.translate.use('en').subscribe(
      value => {
        // value is our translated string
        console.log(value);
      }
```

en.json return log;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the tutorial you provided and could reproduce your problem.

I had also a look in the official documentation of the ngx-translate repository on github and there is a difference to your tutorial.

In the tutorial they are using the Http class of the Angular Http module to load the files:

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

In the official documentation they are using the HttpClient class of the Angular common module. Change the following in your App Module:

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

There is a comment in the official documentation

> NB: if you're still on Angular <4.3, please use Http from @angular/http with http-loader@0.1.0.

Comment: I have added all code from tutorial , but return thats output

Comment: Which angular version are you using?

Comment: 4.1.3  ----------------

Comment: I used http instead of httpClient

Comment: Use @ngx-translate/http-loader version 0.1.0, the latest version of @ngx-translate/core and Http instead of HttpClient. That should fix your problem

Comment: Thanks for all helps brother , I solved problem this tutorial : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-translate

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, that was exactly what i wrote ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the translation framework you're using but it looks from their documentaiton that you want to use a custom translation definition, but you never call:

```
translate.setTranslation('en', myTranslation);
```

where `myTranslation` is your object.

The `'en'` in your code that you're setting as the default is a string (it's in quotes), and looks to be some kind of identifier that the translation service uses to decide what the fallback language is:

> Methods:
>
> setDefaultLang(lang: string): Sets the default language to use as a
>   fallback

You want:

> setTranslation(lang: string, translations: Object, shouldMerge: boolean = false): Manually sets an object of translations for a given language, set shouldMerge to true if you want to append the translations instead of replacing them